# Windows Application in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to write a windows application in Visual Studio 2012 that has a main window and several  forms that open within this window?

I need to gather some information for this kind of applications in visual studio. 
So which kind of project should I focus my studies to (for this kind of applications)?
Any link to other sites or books or anything that gives me a start point is much appreciated.

Comment: The specific answer to the question you asked is "Yes. It is possible to write this type of application in several of the languages that are supported in Visual Studio 2012.". Does that help? I'd guess not, so you should [edit] your question and make it more specific so you can get a more useful answer. The [help] pages have some tips on how to ask questions in a manner that will improve your chances of getting an answer. In its current state, this question is not constructive.

Comment: My specific question is there. I think you've missed it. There's hundreds of project templates in different languages. Which one of them can be used for writing an application with a main window where the forms can be opened **in this window**? I tried **Windows Form Application** in vba and C# but it wasn't what I looked for. (Or at least I couldn't make it what I need). I added some forms that could be opened and read/write data from a sql server. but there wasn't a main window. I could drag the forms all over my three windows. I hope I'm clear enough this time.thank you for your time.

Comment: @Ken White Is it you who deleted the post I accepted as the answer to my question?

Comment: No, it was a moderator who deleted the post. No one except a moderator can usually delete an answer (unless it's very poor and multiple users vote to delete it - usually that happens when it has many downvotes). The [help] can give you information about how (and why) answers are deleted.

Comment: Yes... a moderator did before I could update my answer according to Ken White's comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is an [MDI application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e.aspx).

MDI stand for Multiple-document interface and that kind of application will allow you manage multiple child windows (also called MDI child form) within a parent window (also called MDI parent form).

Here's [a tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973874.aspx) that will help you out getting started with form management inside an MDI application.

Comment: Million thanks. though your previous reply was far enough to satisfy me, I'm so sorry for going through the trouble to change your answer. (I don't use **correct it** 'cause it was correct for me)

Comment: +1.Much better than the deleted answer. It adds sufficient detail to make it useful in the future. Thanks.